# objects in VFP 9 looking for VFP 8 _base.vcx

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have installed VFP 9 on a new PC and transferred some projects from the old machine. I have recompiled the projects in VFP 9 but some objects keep giving me error messages about not finding _base.vcx. They can be looking for it in various locations such as my default directory, the project directory, even in VisualFoxPro 8\ffc (VFP 8 is not on this PC).
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the _base.vcx from VFP9 ffc folder.

Comment: I do. The problem is that it would not record the info after I selected the vcx through the dialog box. I finally had to "use" one of my base vcx and change the path manually. Probably not the best solution but It worked for me...

Comment: @Bernard, sometimes, back-door working the .vcx to the paths is needed.  Glad you got it

Comment: It does record the info if you change something. OTOH, every developer should learn the hack the .pjx files manually. You can open them as tables and replace all Name with strtran( Name, vfp8Path, vfp9Path ),